# How can I reformat a string to exclude leading zeros?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have strings like this:

```
var abc = "002";
var def = "023";
```

How can I easily change the strings so the leading zeros are dropped?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest correct way is:

```
int.Parse(s).ToString();
```

The trim methods all fail for inputs of "0000", they'll return an empty string instead of the correct "0".

Comment: +1 you are right. I took it as the string is always something like 0012, not 0000. You wouldn't remove a leading zero from 0000. Unless you wanted it to be 0 I guess.

Comment: This won't work in a variety of cases - string contains alpha characters, is a string representation of a decimal, or is an integer which is greater than `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: "leading zeros" is a term typically used for strings of digits, and doesn't include a zero in the one's place.  Besides, the example data in the question has only digits.

Comment: I meant decimal such as "0123.1", but I take your point and I'm only being devils advocate. You know what they say about assumptions.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: Did you read the last sentence of my answer?  Without a better specification of the problem, there's no answer which is 100% right.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure that 'removing leading zeros' from "0000" shouldn't result in empty string, but I agree with your comment - this problem is not well defined.

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx):

```
numberString = numberString.TrimStart('0');
```

From MSDN:

> The TrimStart method removes from the current string all leading
>   characters that are in the trimChars parameter. The trim operation
>   stops when a character that is not in trimChars is encountered.

Comment: +1 Much better than the other answer which assumes the value is an integer; values could be "0012ABC" or "00999999999999999999", both of which will fail with `int.Parse`.

Comment: consider this limitation (not on topic, I know)
`System.String TrimStart(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments`

Answer (score 2):

If this is always with int, you can just parse it:

```
abc = int.Parse(abc).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

`var str = int.Parse(abc).ToString();` should do the work I think. Convert number to int, and then just convert it back to string.

Comment: My vote here, because it works also with negative numbers. The solutions using the TrimStart method will fail in such a case.

Comment: doesn't have negative numbers..its a string

Comment: @nologo he means that the TrimStart method will not work for string like "-00123"

Comment: @Mario Vernari But this won't work with "000ABC". Why assume it's going to be an integer?

Comment: I am sorry: for what reason your string starts with zeroes? What kind of content are you supposed to have? Is it a number, a hex, a kind of coding, what else?

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = "0023";
var zeroless = abc.TrimStart('0');
```

output: "23"

Comment: Not on OP's topic, but for people stumbling on this from searches, consider this `TrimStart` limitation:
`System.String TrimStart(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments`

Answer (score 1):

```
        string some_string = "000045";
        string ur_desire = int.Parse(some_string).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(ur_desire);
```

thix ix the good answer i think because it also works with negative number..